# rangeSelector input and export button missalignment

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, linechart

I have highchart with rangeSelector. My problem is when I disable the rangeSelector label the rangeSelector input overlapping with export button. Here is javascvript code for the same

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

    rangeSelector: {
        labelStyle: {
            display: 'none',
        },
    },

    series: [{
        data: usdeur
    }]
});
```

[Here is the fiddle for the same](https://jsfiddle.net/hakkim/akzvtxb5/2/)

Can anyone please help me to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `visibility: 'hidden'` as

[**`labelStyle`**](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/rangeSelector.labelStyle) - CSS styles for the labels - the Zoom, From and To texts

#### **Fiddle**

**OR** Using [**lang options**](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/lang.rangeSelectorZoom) such as

- rangeSelectorZoom
- rangeSelectorFrom
- rangeSelectorTo

#### **Fiddle**